# How do I use relative http urls for Xaml images

Tags: image, xaml

I have a need to treat an image in XAML as a special case and have it download the image using the relative HTTP URL and not the relative DLL path. But I cannot seem to get that to work properly. I've tried the pack URL, but it seems to ignore it. None of these appear to work.

```
<Image Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/images/logo.png" />
<Image Source="~/images/logo.png" />
<Image Source="/images/logo.png" />
```

I would simply like these to work like ordinary HTML img src. I know I can do this in code, but I'm hoping to avoid that if I can.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a way to get this to work. My xap file is loaded from /ClientBin/, so the resulting URLs for the download are actually this:

```
/ClientBin/images/logo.png.
```

Once I realized that was happening, I was able to add URL map to my web.config and an HttpHandler to redirect the image download where I need it to go.